# Updating a field in a table with a number aggregated from other table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a log table with web log entries which have a session ID. I also have a session table summarizing sessions from the previous table. So I have to run some update SQL statement but I don't get how to construct a SQL statement for a field named "session_length". In this field I hope to assign the number of events in that particular session.

Let's say I have the following log table:

```
| Session ID | Timestamp | Action | ...
| 1          | 00:00:00  | get | ...
| 2          | 00:00:00  | get | ...
| 1          | 00:00:01  | get | ...
| 1          | 00:00:02  | get | ...
| 2          | 00:00:02  | get | ...
```

In the session table, I would like to have the following values for session_length field:

```
| Session ID | session_length | ...
| 1          | 3              | ...
| 2          | 2              | ...
```

I am not sure whether this can be done by a single query but I would like to see if this can be done by a single SQL query using update. In particular, I am using PostgresSQL in AWS RedShift.

Comment: What do you mean by "number of events"?  Also, what other fields are going into the summary table?

Comment: I meant the number log entries with the same session ID. There are some other fields such as session start time, user agent and so on but those are populated so need to for separate updating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in the `update` statement:

```
update sessions
    set session_length = (select count(*)
                          from log
                          where log.sessionid = sessions.sessionid
                         )
```